# Convert GetBytes C# line to VB.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a line of code written in C# that I need to convert to Vb.Net.

In C#

I have this block...

```
// Calculate number of 64K blocks
  uint          rowsPerBlock = _MAXBLOCK/widthLength;
  uint          blockSize = rowsPerBlock*widthLength;
  uint          blockCount;
  ushort        length;
  uint          remainder=dcSize;
```

Later the length variable is assigned a value and used for other calculations

```
length = (ushort)((remainder < blockSize) ? remainder : blockSize);

    if (length == remainder)
    {
      comp.WriteByte(0x01);
    }
    else
    {
      comp.WriteByte(0x00);
    }

    comp.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(length), 0, 2);

    // Write one's compliment of LEN
```

All of the above I have converted, except the following line.

```
comp.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)~length), 0, 2);
```

What would be the correct conversion for this line?

Thanks

Comment: [C# to VB](http://converter.telerik.com/) converter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would use [`Not`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cwcswt4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in VB.Net to perform a bitwise negation:

```
comp.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(CUShort(Not length)), 0, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
Dim byteArray As Byte( ) = BitConverter.GetBytes( (CUShort)Not length)
comp.Write(byteArray , 0, 2);
```

Link BitConverter.GetBytes : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/fk3sts66.aspx#Y0

Link Not : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/2cwcswt4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx